# Confusion with Heaviside Step Function and Ramp Function.

Tags: special-functions, graphing-functions

I want to know how to represent the following graph with Heaviside step functions and ramp functions.

[image]

My guess is that this is represented as $r(t) -r(t-2) +2u(t-2)$, where $r(t)$ is the unit ramp function and $u(t)$ is the Heaviside unit step function.
If this is true then since the delayed ramp function is $r(t-a) = (t-a)u(t-a)$ (according to [here](https://books.google.gr/books?id=RFt71hPuprQC&pg=SA5-PA20&lpg=SA5-PA20&dq=delayed%20ramp%20function&source=bl&ots=W5STtrRwgp&sig=RE-Fx2IA6gMlJK17GTxHPyEF7es&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBmoVChMIn9y4zrG9xwIVRDwaCh2g5w3e#v=onepage&q=delayed%20ramp%20function&f=false)) then the same graph can also be represented as $tu(t) -(t-2)u(t-2) +2u(t-2)$. However i draw this function in Matlab and it shows something else instead. I've very confused with this type of problem for a long time now. I don't know what i'm doing wrong. What is the connection between $r(t)$ and $u(t)$? Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we define the ramp function $r$ as

$$
r(t)=
\begin{cases}
t, & t\ge 0\\\\
0, & t<0
\end{cases}$$

then the function $f$ plotted in the post can be represented as

$$f(t)=r(t)-r(t-2)$$

Note that if one introduces (i.e., adds) a step function, the resulting plot would exhibit a jump discontinuity.  Inasmuch as the plot exhibits no jump, then the function it represents can have no such step function.

Comment: I've tested it. Now everything works. That was bothering me for a long time and as it turns out one of my teachers gave me a wrong answer to this! That and then Matlab confused me. Thank you very much! You saved me! I feel so relieved.

Comment: One more thing if you could answer please. The derivative $\frac{d\ r(t-a)}{dt} = u(t-a)$? Is this true?

Comment: You are quite welcome. My pleasure.  And yes, the derivative of the unit ramp is the unit step, except of course at $t=0$.  At zero, the ramp's derivative is undefined.